# Read sheet to dataframe from a pandas ExcelWriter object

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I have a pandas ExcelWriter object with several sheets, which were loaded from an excel spreadsheet.  I'd like to read out a sheet as a dataframe now.  I know I could read it from the original excel spreadsheet, but I'd like to retrieve the data from the ExcelWriter object.

The sheets are being loaded using openpyxl

```
testwriter = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine = 'openpyxl')
testwriter.book = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
testwriter.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(testwriter.sheets['sheetname']) ???
```

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly straightforward to convert an existing openpyxl worksheet to a Pandas dataframe. While version 2.4 will provide the best support for this, the principle is the same for all versions: loop over the rows in the sheet and return the cell values.

See [openpyxl 2.4 documentation for working with Pandas](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/2.4/pandas.html) for some ideas.

BTW. there is no need to create the `testwriter.sheets` dictionary: use `book['sheetname'].